# Prettier integration by ESLint rules in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm, eslint, prettier

I created the rules in ESLint, how can I make Prettier format the code according to the rules specified in ESLint.

**.eslintrc.js**

```
  module.exports = {
   rules: {
      quotes: ["error", "single"]
   }
  };
```

Before saving:

[image: before saving]

After saving, Prettier automatically formats the code:

[image: after saving, Prettier automatically formats the code.]

I want to use Prettier and ESLint. Without using `.prettierrc.js -> singleQuote: true,`. in order for Prettier to format the file according to the ESLint rules, before saving, Prettier takes the rules specified in eslintrc.js and formats the code. How can I do this?

In VSCode User Settings, set `"prettier.eslintIntegration": true`

what about WebStorm?

Comment: Docs? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/eslint.html

Comment: Same on WebStorm forums? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003325440-Prettier-integration-by-ESlint-rules

Comment: LazyOne, yes, the same

Answer (score 7):

I'll take a project created with the [create-nuxt-app](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app) utility, where **ESLint** and **Prettier** are already properly configured for this example.

*For reference only, here's what the config files look like. Open spoilers to see if needed.*

.prettierrc

> [image: .prettierrc]

.eslintrc.js

> [image: .eslintrc.js]

.editorconfig

> [image: .editorconfig]

.package.json

> [image]

Next, follow these steps to set up your IDE:

1. Re-import a project.

   To do it, you should  remove the `.idea` directory from the project root. Then
   import the project again. Note that you will lose all project related settings. But
   this step is necessary because the IDE configures the *Code Style* and *Editor
   settings* during import. You can check this by opening the Event Log.

   [image: Event Log]
2. Open `.prettierrc` and in the dialog "Use code style based on Prettier for this
   project?" choose **No**.

   [image: .prettierrc, choose No here]
3. Open **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | ESLint**
   And make sure the **Automatic ESLint configuration** checkbox is enabled.

   [image: ESLint configuration]
4. Then open **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Prettier** and configure
   the **Prettier package**.

   [image: Prettier configuration]

   Now when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> the
   file will be formatted according to **Prittier** settings.

   But this option does not suit us, since not all rules specified for **ESLint** will
   apply. We need to run `eslint --fix` instead, which will format the file according to
   **Prettier** settings.

   So let's assign the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+
   <kbd>P</kbd> to run `eslint --fix`.
5. Remove the **Format with Prettier** shortcut in **Settings | Keymap**.

   [image: Delete format with Prettier shortcut]
6. Then reassign the shortcut to **Fix ESLint problems**.

   [image: Fix ESLint problems shortcut setup]

Now when you run <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> your file will be correctly formatted.